# Select Statements in LINQ Efficiency

Tags: c#, linq, select

For code shown below, I'm wondering is there a more efficient way of assigning the Status and Types in the select statement? There is no relationship between the contract and the statuses/types as the contract items are coming from an API call and the statuses/types are from a local database.

The part in question is

```
Status = statuses.FirstOrDefault(y => y.StatusId == x.StatusId)
Type = types.FirstOrDefault(y => y.TypeId == x.TypeId)
```

Is there a better way of assigning these?

```
var statuses = this.StatusRepository.GetActiveStatuses().ToList();
var types = this.TypeRepository.GetActiveTypes().ToList();
var contracts = this.ContractApi.GetCurrentContracts().Select(x => new ContractItem {
        Id = x.Id,
        Name = x.Name,
        Status = statuses.FirstOrDefault(y => y.StatusId == x.StatusId) ?? Status.Empty(),
        Type = types.FirstOrDefault(y => y.TypeId == x.TypeId) ?? Type.Empty()
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For better performance you should use a dictionary or lookup:

```
var statuses = this.StatusRepository.GetActiveStatuses().ToLookup(x => x.StatusId);
var types = this.TypeRepository.GetActiveTypes().ToLookup(x => x.TypeId);
var emptyStatus = Status.Empty();
var emptyType = Type.Empty();

var contracts = this.ContractApi.GetCurrentContracts()
    .Select(x => new ContractItem {
        Id = x.Id,
        Name = x.Name,
        Status = statuses[x.StatusId].DefaultIfEmpty(emptyStatus).First(),
        Type = types[x.TypeId].DefaultIfEmpty(emptyType).First()
    });
```

The lookup is more readable because it enables to use `DefaultIfEmpty`

Comment: This is pretty cool. I've never seen this done. Thank you and @Milney for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you know they will exist in your local database you could store them in a Dictionary like;

```
var statusDict = this.StatusRepository.GetActiveStatuses().ToDictionary(s => s.StatusId);

....

Status = statusDict[x.StatusId]
```

Comment: To duplicate the OP's original functionality, you should call `statusDict.TryGetValue(x.StatusId, out Status)`.

Comment: Is that dictionary just storing the StatusIds? Because the Status and Type in the select statement are objects.

Comment: The dictionary stored the object BY its Id as the key. So you can pass in the Id, and it returns you the object, faster than looking through the whole list each time...

Comment: Refer to Tim's answer as it is a better one, I typed this is a hurry and was planning to edit after but his is complete

Comment: Awesome, thank you for your help. Learned something new today!